# remove currency symbol ( $ ) in category page in magento2

Tags: magento2, jquery-ui-slider

I have created a custom weight attribute of price type and i want to  remove currency symbol ( $ ) this attribute. and show category page the weight slider in category page
give me solution
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKTNE.png)
see this image given below i have created a a custom weight attribute of price type